# Error while opening JSON-object in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

Im quite new at working with JSON-objects. So, my program saves some tweets and in a JSON object. The storing part looks like:

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        with open('Saved data/' + filename + '.json', 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(data)
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print('Error on_data: %s' % str(e))
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
    return True

if stream:
    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
    twitter_stream.filter(track=[tracking_string])
```

which generates a json object with some tweets without any empty lines and so on (checked in notepad).

The opening part looks like this:

```
with open('saved data/' + filename + '.json', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
        print('mark')
```

Which prints 'mark' one time. But for the second iteration I get an error at the "tweet = json.loads(line)" saying

```
JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Seems like there is a problem reaching row no. 2 in the file, but I really don't get why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the contents of `line`? `print`  it after `for` line so that you can see the offending data.

Comment: `line` is just getting printed the first time, and it holds one tweet. I'm getting the same error as before and line is not printed the second iteration even though I put `print(line)` before the `loads()`.

Comment: It means that you are getting error in the first `line` or the second `line` is empty. Try something like `print('Current line:', line)`

Comment: printing 'Current line:' second iteration but then the error.

Comment: Then the second line is empty. Are you sure each line contains a valid JSON string?

Comment: No, I'm not. Thought that was made during the saving process.

Answer (score 0):

save to json:

```
json_text = json.dumps(your_dictionary, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

with open(filename, 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json_text)
```

read a json:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as json_file:
    text = json_file.read()
dictionary = json.loads(text)
```

Why are you reading the file in lines?

Comment: I can't load this way. Might that be because the different tweets have different dictionaries?